# Problems creating panel with multiple rectangles

Tags: java, graphics, rectangles

I am trying to create a panel that shows the history of some "maps" we store.
The earliest at the top, followed by those later with extra information at times.

The main code for HistoryGraph thus far is:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

/**
 * @author woo Apr 29, 2013
 * 
 *         TODO
 * 
 *         freemind freemind.database.graphics
 */
public class HistoryGraph extends JPanel
{

   public HistoryGraph()
   {
      super();
   }

   private List<HistoryNode> nodes = new ArrayList<HistoryNode>();

   public void add( int startX, int startY, HistoryNode node )
   {
      node.setPosition( startX, startY );
      nodes.add( node );
      System.out.println( "There are now " + nodes.size() + " nodes" );
   }

   @Override
   public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
   {
      Graphics2D g2 = ( Graphics2D ) g;
      g2.setColor( getBackground() );

      g2.fillRect( getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight() );

      g2.setColor( Color.black );
      int lastX = 0;
      int lastY = 0;
      int k = 0;
      for ( int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++ )
      {
         HistoryNode node = nodes.get( i );
         node.paintComponent( g2 );
         if ( k > 0 )
         {
            int x = node.getX() + node.getWidth() / 2;
            int y = node.getY();
            g2.draw( new Line2D.Double( lastX, lastY, x, y ) );
         }
         lastX = node.getX() + node.getWidth() / 2;
         lastY = node.getY() + node.getHeight();
         k++;
      }
   }

   /**
    * @param args
    */
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      JFrame f = new JFrame( "History of Map X" );
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      List<HistoryNode> nodes = new ArrayList<HistoryNode>();
      HistoryGraph panel = new HistoryGraph();
      panel.setBackground( Color.green );
      nodes.add( new HistoryNode( "2012-04-09,Version 1.2" ) );
      nodes.add( new HistoryNode( "2012-05-01,Release 1.1" ) );
      nodes.add( new HistoryNode( "2012-05-03,Release 1.2,Version 1.3,Test" ) );
      int x = 50;
      int y = 50;
      int deltaY = 100;
      for ( int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++ )
      {
         HistoryNode node = nodes.get( i );

     node.setBackground( Color.orange );
     panel.add( x, y, node );
     y += deltaY;
  }
```

And the code for HistoryNode is:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * @author woo Apr 29, 2013
 * 
 *         TODO
 * 
 *         freemind freemind.database.graphics
 */

public class HistoryNode extends JPanel
{

   public HistoryNode( String text )
   {
      super();
      this.text = text;
   }

   private double x;
   private double y;
   private double width;
   private double height;

   private String text;

   private Double r;

   @Override
   public int getHeight()
   {
      return ( int ) height;
   }

   @Override
   public int getWidth()
   {
      return ( int ) width;
   }

   @Override
   public int getX()
   {
      return ( int ) x;
   }

   @Override
   public int getY()
   {
      return ( int ) y;
   }

   @Override
   public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
   {
      super.paintComponent( g );
      Graphics2D g2d = ( Graphics2D ) g;

      g2d.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
         RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON );
      FontRenderContext frc = g2d.getFontRenderContext();
      Font font = g2d.getFont().deriveFont( 12f );
      g2d.setFont( font );

      List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
      StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer( text, "," );
      float sw = 0.0f;
      float sh = 0.0f;
      List<Float> depths = new ArrayList<Float>();
      List<Float> widths = new ArrayList<Float>();
      List<Float> descents = new ArrayList<Float>();
      while ( tokenizer.hasMoreTokens() )
      {
         String s = tokenizer.nextToken();
         float sb = ( float ) font.getStringBounds( s, frc ).getWidth();
         widths.add( sb );
         if ( sb > sw )
         {
            sw = sb;
         }
         lines.add( s );
         LineMetrics lm = font.getLineMetrics( s, frc );
         float depth = lm.getAscent() + lm.getDescent();
         depths.add( depth );
         if ( depth > sh )
         {
            sh = depth;
         }
         descents.add( lm.getDescent() );
      }
      width = sw + 10;
      double padding = sh;
      height = ( descents.size() ) * sh + padding;
      r = new Rectangle2D.Double( x, y, width, height );
      g2d.setColor( getBackground() );
      g2d.fillRect( getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight() );
      g2d.setColor( Color.black );
      g2d.draw( r );
      float dy = 0.0f;
      for ( int i = 0; i < depths.size(); i++ )
      {
         sh = depths.get( i );
         sw = widths.get( i );
         float descent = descents.get( i );
         // scale text to fit and center in r
         float sx = ( float ) ( r.x + ( r.width - sw ) / 2 );
         float sy = dy + ( float ) ( r.y + sh + padding / 2 );
         dy += sh;
         String s = lines.get( i );
         g2d.drawString( s, sx, sy );
      }
   }

   /**
    * @param startX
    * @param startY
    */
   public void setPosition( int startX, int startY )
   {
      x = startX;
      y = startY;
   }
}
```

Now, things work reasonably well, EXCEPT that I get an extra area on the HistoryGraph that I can't explain located at (0,0).  I've colored the HistoryNodes orange to see what was happening and it's on top of the first node.  I checked that I'm only creating 3 nodes and only drawing 3 nodes.

Here is a picture of what I get:

(http://jwooten37830.com/~woo/problems/HistoryGraph.JPG)

Also, How should I set the size for the panel so that the outside frame is smaller than the HistoryGraph, but will have scroll bars?  The way I have it it's always the "right" size.  If my graph gets longer, I want to limit the outside size to say 500 deep, but the inside might be 1000.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

The first is `g2.fillRect( getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight() );`, the second is your not calling `super.paintComponent`

The problem with you `fillRect` call is that by the time any of your paint methods are called, the graphics context has already been translated to the components coordinate space (ie the components location)

This means when you call `fillRect`, you are effectively calling `getX() + getX(), getY() + getY()`

This means that all painitng is done with the concept that the top, left corner of the component is at 0x0.

By calling `super.paintComponent`, you will, effectively do what you are trying to achieve.

Just remember, the graphics context is set to the components background color and font by default. So if you want to paint your component a particular color, you should set the components background color (out side of the paint methods)

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

**Updated**

I'm kind of embarressed to say I missed this, but, you shouldn't be doining this...

```
@Override
public int getHeight()
{
   return ( int ) height;
}

@Override
public int getWidth()
{
   return ( int ) width;
}

@Override
public int getX()
{
   return ( int ) x;
}

@Override
public int getY()
{
   return ( int ) y;
}
```

These are use by the Swing framework internally to position and size your component. They are also required to provide event notification when the change.  Altering them (in the way you have) can have unexpected results (which you are suffering)...

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I guess I'm not understanding something though.  I removed all of the fillRect, and added the super.paintComponent where it was missing.  I now only set the background of the HistoryGraph in the main program.  I get a complete green background, with the HistoryNodes also in green, and a lightGray square in the upper left at 0,0.  How is that getting drawn?  I.e. without the fillRects, I get exactly the same as before just no orange squares and one light gray one in the upper left.

Comment: I have noticed that it draws correctly, but any resize event causes the extra shapes to appear in the upper left corner, while leaving everything else alone. I read the sources you mentioned, but don't see anything about multiple drawings like I'm doing and don't see where I've deviated.

Comment: On reading, still not understanding how I get HistoryGraph to display it's component HistoryNodes.  Documentation says I shouldn't call paintComponent myself.  If I don't in the HistoryGraph paintComponent method, the nodes don't get drawn!  If I do, then they are drawn correctly, but resize creates artifacts.  What am I not storing correctly in HistoryNode or HistoryGraph for the redraw?

Comment: I finally found out what was wrong and fixed it.  It basically had nothing to do with any of the above, although doing super.paintComponent was needed.

What was actually happening was that HistoryGraphic was my panel where I was doing drawing, but I was attempting to do it in a more OO manner, by creating a class HistoryNode that knew how to draw itself and expected to be able to add them to the HistoryGraphic class, position them, and they would draw themselves.  However, because HistoryGraphic and HistoryNode were both extending JPanel,
when HistoryNodes were added, they were at 0,0, BUT

Comment: Then drew themselves at the problem locations!   When I used to do this using Canvas, it was not the same kind of problem. 
Solution:  Make HistoryNode extend Object, change paintComponent to draw and just use it in HistoryGraphic as a convenience.  When HistoryGraphic is told to paint, it goes though the HistoryNodes and tells them to paint.  Done!  Since they are not added to the panel, they have no visible artifacts.  I've seen no good examples of how to actually do this using OO more.  I.e. Add panels to panels without using layouts, but absolute positioning.